# I wanna know solving method of this differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$t^2 y'' - t(t + 2)y' + (t+2)y = 2t^3 $

How should I solve this differential equation?

I cannot solve this equation using y=x^m  .

And How should I find general solution?

Please. I need your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let us solve the homogeneous problem
\begin{align}
t^2y''-t(t+2)y' + (t+2)y = 0.
\end{align}
Let us guess a solution of the form
\begin{align}
y = t+a. \ \ \ (*)
\end{align}
Substitue $(\ast)$ back into the differential equation yields
\begin{align}
-t(t+2) + (t+2)(t+a) = 0
\end{align}
which mean $a=0$. Thus $y=t$ is a solution. Now, let us use reduction of order to find another solution. Suppose
\begin{align}
y_2(t) = tv(t) \ \ \ (**)
\end{align}
is another solution to the homogeneous problem. Substitue $(**)$ back into the differential equation yields
\begin{align}
t^2(2v'+tv'') -t(t+2)(v+tv') +(t+2)tv = t^3(v''-v') = 0.
\end{align}
Solving
\begin{align}
v''-v' = 0
\end{align}
yields a solution $v = e^t$. Thus, $y_2 = te^t$ is another homogeneous solution. 
The rest is standard which I will leave for the reader.